# Check if object is UIKeyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikeyboard

I was wondering if anyone has a clever way to check to see if an object is of type `UIKeyboard`? I can't use the `UIKeyboardDidShow` notifications, because I'm using them to bring up other inputView classes aside from the keyboard so I have to be able to differentiate between which inputView is currently on the screen (ie I have one that pops up on the screen that has a control panel that lets you change the color of something).

Using `[view isKindOfClass:[UIKeyboard class]]` doesn't work because UIKeyboard is not recognized and I can't import it's .h file without getting an error.

Does anyone know what I could do here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use reflection.

```
[view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIKeyboard")]
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what you're asking, you could either ask an input view if it's the first responder, or you could check the inputView property to see if its set, if it's nil, it's the keyboard.

```
UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
if( [field isFirstResponder] ) {
    //Currently being used to input something
}

if( [field inputView] != nil ) {
    //User is not using a default keyboard
}
```

Comment: In fairness to the above answer, I had to mark them correct because they answered my question (without me realizing I didn't even have the keyboard view). But your solution is the one I ended up using because I didn't even realize the inputView was nil. Gave you a point up, thanks!